# NetCDF variables that have the fill value/ missing value

Tags: python, netcdf

I have a variable in a NetCDF file that has a default value if the variable is null.  How do you remove this value or change it to 0 when the variable is missing a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that when the variable is populated into the NetCDF file, it is set to insert some default value for values that are missing. Now, I am assuming that you need to remove these default values *after* the file has been written and you are working with the data.

So (depending on how you are accessing the variable) I would pull the variable out of the NetCDF file and assign it to a python variable. This is the first method that comes to mind.

Use a for loop to step through and replace that default value with 0

```
variable=NetCDF_variable  #Assume default value is 1e10
cleaned_list=[]
for i in variable:
    if i == 1e10:
        cleaned_list.append(0)  #0 or whatever you want to fill here
    else: 
        cleaned_list.append(i)
```

If the default value is a float, you may want to look into [numpy.isclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) if the above code isn't working. You might also be interested in [masking](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) your data in case any computations you do would be thrown off by inserting a 0.

EDIT: User N1B4 provided a much cleaner and efficient way of doing the exact same thing as above.

```
variable[variable == 1e10] = 0
```

Comment: Since netCDF variables are cast to numpy arrays, `variable[variable == 1e10] = 0` accomplishes the same as above and can work on multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: I knew there was a faster way, I'm still learning shorthand like this. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll add it to the answer